# jQuery event on multi select html element not working on iOS

Tags: jquery, html, ios, multi-select

I am trying to create a multi-select html element on my page with a mix of regular and "uncombinable" options, i.e. some options cannot be combined in the multi-selection and act as Single selects. Selecting these uncombinable options deselects any other currently selected options.

I am using click and touchstart event handler to implement this behavior in the control.

Here's the code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var selected = [];
   $(".multiSelectOptions").bind("click touchstart", function() {
     var selOption = this.value;
     if (selOption === "Four" || selOption === "Five") {
       if (selected.indexOf(selOption) === -1) {
         $("#mySelect").attr("selected", false);
         $("#mySelect").val(selOption);
         selected = [];
         selected.push(selOption);
       } else {
         selected = [];
       }
     } else {
       if (selected.indexOf("Four") !== -1 || selected.indexOf("Five") !== -1) {
         selected = [];
         $("#mySelect").attr("selected", false);
         $("#mySelect").val(selOption);
       }
       if (selected.indexOf(selOption) === -1) {
         selected.push(selOption);
       } else {
         selected.splice(selected.indexOf(selOption), 1);
       }
     }
     $('#result').text(selected);
   });
 });
```

```css
.mselect {
  width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" class="mselect" multiple='multiple'>
  <option class="multiSelectOptions" value="One">One</option>
  <option class="multiSelectOptions" value="Two">Two</option>
  <option class="multiSelectOptions" value="Three">Three</option>
  <option class="multiSelectOptions" value="Four">Four (uncombinable)</option>
  <option class="multiSelectOptions" value="Five">Five (uncombinable)</option>
  <option class="multiSelectOptions" value="Six">Six</option>
  <option class="multiSelectOptions" value="Seven">Seven</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/r6L31yr9/17/

The solution is working as expected on all web browsers except iOS. The  html element is rendered in a native popover in iOS (as desired) but the selection is not restricted by jQuery. it works as a regular multi-select element on iOS.

Any tips to get this working without using any jQuery plugins or widgets?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I haven't tested it on iOs, but the right way to do you bindings is with `change`. For example: `$("#mySelect").bind("change", func...`. Try that and let me know

Comment: Any chance you can remote debug (Mac required AFAIK)? (Worse case scenario; Do some stupid alert between lines to see if it breaks on latest Safari on iOS as no-Mac workaround)

Comment: @RCorrie I tried the change event before, but could not implement what I wanted as it does not give me the last selected option (in the multiselect). It just gives me an array of the selected options. This is why I had to work with the other events.

Comment: @MarvinSmit I tried the jsfiddle on iOS which does not trigger the event. I am going to try it on a Mac and I will update soon.